# Huge scene - scatter wont work / cant scale scene down

Tags: transforms, volumetrics

I am a bit stuck here.
I have a very large scene (scifi concept art with 2km tall building + 150km environment). I started with realistic sizes, but now I have to deal with this incredibly large scene. I already changed the units so its easier to work.

I want to use a principled volumetric scatter, but i cant set it correctly. 0,00001 doesnt show a thing, and 0,00002 turns everything dark.
[image]

I also scaled down my scene, but this ended up in destroying almost any asset. (I dont know how to fix that.)
[image]

Can you help me? What could I do?
Thanks!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Move the scene closer to the world origin.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)